# Fly.io Launch Issue: "Error failed to fetch an image or build from source: error building: error during connect: Post..."

Tags: node.js, docker, fly

I am new to Docker and Fly.io, and trying to get a very basic Nodejs backend hosted, but running into an error. You can see my repo [here](https://github.com/ktpeace/milkwall). Locally, I've added a Dockerfile to `backend/` that looks like this:

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --omit=dev
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Then, in WSL2, I ran `docker build .` and `docker run -dp 5000:5000 [image ID]`. The backend is showing at `localhost:5000` as well as feeding data to the frontend correctly.

But when I run `flyctl launch`, it keeps giving me `Error failed to fetch an image or build from source: error building: error during connect: Post "http://[a very long URL]": EOF`.

Someone suggested that the auto-generated fly.toml defaulting to `internal_port = 8080` was the issue, so I tried changing it to match Express and Docker with `5000`, but got the same error.

Just in case: I have a bad Internet connection and I don't know if that could be the problem--a timeout?

Can someone help me??

Comment: ya its timeout issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this and I'm posting it here for others who I saw had the same issue.

- I have read that you need a host of '0.0.0.0' in the `app.listen`, so that was there (didn't solve my issue but maybe someone else's)
- destroyed the fly attempted build
- deleted the fly.toml
- deleted the Docker container and image
- changed my backend port to 8080 across my project (the auto-generated fly.toml makes `internal_port = 8080` no matter what the Dockerfile says)
- remade the Docker container and image
- ran `flyctl launch` again

My guess is that the problem was that just altering the 5000 to 8080 in the fly.toml file that had been made during a failed build was not enough. It needed to be correct from the start.